# Display square image div as frame regardless of image width and height

Tags: css, image, html, layout

Maybe this has been asked before and I simply don't know what to look for. Anyways, I have tried quite hard to find anything on this topic but by now I didn't came across anything helpful.

[image]

I hope though that the question is quite simple. I want to display divs as a frame of images that user post. The divs should be squares but still they should be filled by the pictures.

Here is a perfect example: http://500px.com/popular The squares are always filled completely but still the image is not changed in any way. As far as I can see, simply an image part is displayed regardless of width and height.

How can this be accomplished?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: First and foremost, it IS cropping the images. I'll fiddle something for you real quick. One moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely try something like this. You can use the `background-size` property to fill your `box`es with the image you'd like to utilize. This will *not* maintain aspect ratio, but force the entire `img` to fill the square.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cukgh/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    float:left;
    margin:15px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:url('http://www.hdwallpapers3g.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Images-6.jpg');
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

**If you would like to maintain the aspect ratio, but only crop the longer width/height, use `background-size:cover`**

### EDIT:

If you would like to dynamically set the image, utilize a small `script` to do so.

#### Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/cukgh/2/

*If you have further questions, please post a different question in the forums. A single question is meant to identify a single problem and solve it.*

Comment: Okay. This looks pretty good. However, I do ask myself how it is possible to dynamically load an CSS image as I want to display user images???

Comment: You would have to use a script of some sort for anything `dynamic`. Let me introduce a new fiddle. One moment.

Comment: wow man you're awesome and a great help. Thanks! I would have tried something myself first but I really didnt find any proper info on that topic. I havent even heard of :cover before.

Comment: Added answer for you. If you feel this answer was acceptable for your question please select the green checkbox near the voting bar to 'accept' the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I strongly believe you could also help me with another thing that I have been dealing with a long time now. Its also concerned with images. You would say I should post another question?

Comment: Please do. I'm an experienced coder, but I'm still a fish in a sea of sharks. Exposure is what you need, not a dedicated helper. Post a new question and add it here as a comment if you'd like so I can track it. Somebody may have a better answer than me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176543/laravel-4-1-how-to-compare-image-height-and-width-within-a-function

Comment: Everything has worked VERY well so far. Now I am getting this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180263/dynamically-change-div-css-background-using-js-within-blade-foreach-loop

Answer (score 1):

In CSS you could try background-size: cover;  ?  You'd have to set the images as the background image, but then there's all sorts of background- styles you can apply to it.

Edit: cover is what you're after I think.