# Laravel 4.1, how to compare image height and width within a function

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-4, compare

I am trying to determine in which way an image has to be cropped to fit perfectly as a square user profile image.

I have discovered the Laravel package "intervention image" but as far as I can see this one does not offer a function to compare whether an image is horizontal or vertical.

http://intervention.olivervogel.net/

Is there any good way to determine whether the image is a square or horizontal or vertical before resizing and cropping it?

This is what I do at the moment:

```
$img->resize(400, null, true)->crop(400, 400);
```

It works perfectly for squares obviously and it works pretty good for vertical but it does not work very well for horizontal images.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd personally use a `JS` script to determine it. One second.

Comment: Added answer to determine what you'd like to do. All you would have to do otherwise is include the `add css` code I provided in the previous question you posted for each conditional. I'd set a `horizontal` class, `vertical` class, and a `square` class. [Like this Fiddle. You will have to define the classes in CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/PD4a2/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### So, here's my take on it.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/PD4a2/1/

**HTML:**

```
<img id="img1" src="http://hdwallpaper2013.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Download-Flower-Background-Images-HD-Wallpaper.jpg" />

<img id="img2" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_74so2YIdYpM/TEd09Hqrm6I/AAAAAAAAApY/rwGCm5_Tawg/s1600/tall%2Bcopy.jpg" />

<img id="img3" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Love_Heart_symbol_square.svg" />
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
    max-width:500px;
    max-height:500px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function findSize(x){
    var h = x.height();
    var w = x.width();
    if(h<w){
       alert("Image is wider than it is tall.");
    } else if(w<h){
       alert("Image is taller than it is tall.");
    } else {
       alert("Image is square.");
    }
}
findSize($('#img1'));
findSize($('#img2'));
findSize($('#img3'));
```

#### Gives you a definitive comparison of which values are either taller, wider, or square.

All you would have to do otherwise is include the `add css` code I provided in the previous question you posted for each conditional. I'd set a `horizontal` class, `vertical` class, and a `square` class. [Like this Fiddle. You will have to define the classes in CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/PD4a2/3/)

**Obviously I just set a border color, but you could do whatever you wanted at this point.**

Comment: Your answers are by far the best I had by now. I wish I could upvote this a few times. Thanks a lot!

Comment: just did so. If you want to have a look at another one of my questions I would be happy. Just if you want to of course.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200492/laravel-4-1-find-hashtags-in-string

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getimagesize($link)`, which returns an array with the width and height of an image.  Then just check horizontal or vertical or square using:

```
<?php
function WvsH ($link) {
    $size = getimagesize($link);
    if ($size[0] < $size[1]) {
        return 'vertical';
    }
    else if ($size[1] < $size[0]) {
        return 'horizontal';
    }
    else {
        return 'square';
    }
}
?>
```

Of course, that is assuming that the link exists.

Comment: You're welcome.  It should work for any GIF, JPG, PNG, SWF, SWC, PSD, TIFF, BMP, IFF, JP2, JPX, JB2, JPC, XBM, or WBMP file.