# How to find #hashtags in strings using Laravel 4.1?

Tags: php, string, input, laravel, laravel-4

I am currently trying to filter through an Input string to find the single hashtags that a user wants to be displayed with his photo. However, I am currently getting inserts in my database that are not correct.

The best case scenario would be that every single hashtag is saved in a new database row with the photo id. However, I do not really know what to do to accomplish that.

```
$hashtag = new Hashtag;

     $hashtag->photo_id = $photo->id;

        $hashtag_string = Input::get('hashtags');

            $hashtag_string = Str::contains($hashtag_string, '#')

        $hashtag->hashtag = $hashtag_string;


$hashtag->save();
```

I found some functions in this cheat sheet (http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca) but I do not get them to work properly.

Comment: Str::contains() returns bool
http://laravel.com/api/function-str_contains.html

Comment: Yeah that what I realised as well when I had a look at my db. So what to use then?

Comment: Not enough context for your question.

Comment: What do you have to know? I can add infos.

Comment: strpos() instead of Str::contains() -- E: okay I Don' t understand what your code tries to do.

Comment: not sure what you're trying to accomplish, maybe try writing another example?

Comment: The community in the past has decided that [tags are best not in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). Thus, if you can write your titles as ordinary sentences, there'll be less future editing required. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = $hashtag_string;

       preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/', $str, $matches);


       foreach ($matches[1] as $hashtag_name) {

       $hashtag =   Hashtag::firstOrCreate(array('hashtag' => $hashtag_name));

                                    }
```

You could then, in this foreach loop, connect those hashtags to a post (or in your case a photo) or sth.